# How to return an int array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, return

I'm learning C# and I have a problem with a function.

It should multiply elements of the int array "tab" by the int value of "mnoznik" and return new int array "wyj".

I tried many things but I still have no idea on how to solve it.

```
static int mnozenie(int[] tab, int mnoznik)
{
    int[] wyj;
    wyj = new int[tab.Length];
    if (mnoznik != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.Length; i++)
            wyj[i] = tab[i] * mnoznik;
        return wyj[];
    } else
        return 0;
```

Comment: Have your return type as `int[][]` and return `null` in else part.

Answer (score 7):

try

```
static int[] mnozenie(int[] tab, int mnoznik)
{
    int[] wyj = new int[tab.Length];
    if (mnoznik != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.Length; i++)
            wyj[i] = tab[i] * mnoznik;
    }
    return wyj;

}
```

Comment: The OP wants the value `0` if the input `mnoznik` is 0. IMHO, that means it would make more sense to always `return wyj;` and just skip the multiplication loop if `mnoznik` is 0.

Comment: This worked perfectly (to create and return an int array)...

Answer (score 1):

```
static int[] mnozenie(int[] tab, int mnoznik)
{
    if (tab.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.Length; i++)
        {
            tab[i] *= mnoznik;
        }
        return tab;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Or alternatively instead of return null just return `tab` back.

The `if` block just protects from trying to access a null collection, or you could just handle the exception in whatever way you choose.

Comment: or alternatively instead of return null just return tab back, the if block just protects from trying to access a null collection, or just handle the exception in whatever way you choose.

Comment: where u store result of multiplication ?

Comment: yes u assign result to local field item which is never declared ... in the original method is result of multiplication stored in array

Comment: I'm sorry, but thats just not accurate. If the original int[] tab is never declared then that is handled with the if block, if it is declared then I store the result of the multiplication for each element in the element and pass the new int[] tab back. In fact declaring another int[] or any more variables would be a complete waste of resources as they are unneeded.

Comment: furthermore, you are welcome and even encouraged to test the above code to see if it works.

Comment: in that case all multiplication would be stored in array which should be output of method....

Comment: I swapped out the foreach block with a for block, and yes all multiplication is stored right back in the input array, and is indeed the output

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to return both an array and an integer, which you can't do.  You can wrap it all in a Tuple<,> and return both, or you can return null in the case mnoznik is 0.

Something like:

```
static Tuple<bool,int[]> mnozenie(int[] tab, int mnoznik)
{
    return (mnoznik == 0)
           ? new Tuple<bool,int[]>(false, new [] { 0 })
           : new Tuple<bool,int[]>(true, tab.Select(i => i*mnoznik).ToArray());
}
```

or

```
static int mnozenie(int[] tab, int mnoznik)
{
    return (mnoznik == 0)
           ? null
           : tab.Select(i => i*mnoznik).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: in your second example has method int return type and u returned int array

Comment: That was a typo.  I should've written int[].

Another thing is that instead of null, you might return a well-defined array, like I did in the first example:  new [] { 0 };

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if this code might be able to help you!

```
static int[] m(int[] a , int low , int big) 
{
    int[] re = new int[2];
    int min, max, mid ;
    if (low == big)
    {
        min = max = a[low];
        re[0] = min;
        re[1] = max;
        return (re);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

correct me if I'm wrong but I'm something like 90% sure that in case of returning arrays or any kind of element in c#/c++. The compiler actually doesn't actually  move the value itself, in the stack from one memory location to another, it just pushes the pointer/handle to that specific memory, where the information is stored up the stack.

by specifying

> return wyj[];

you're actually trying to return the array itself, and not the pointer. Which would be illegal, but my simply removing the the square brackies, you're moving the pointer and complier is happycamper.
[EDIT: missed words]